javac --patch-module doesn't work as expected at compile time
I want to compile my program with the use of the internal API of a modular java library which in addition is package-private. In the future I also want to fine-tune the package access at runtime to not export to all unnamed.
The library:
module com.jcraft.jsch {
  exports com.jcraft.jsch;
  ...
}
...
package com.jcraft.jsch.jzlib;
final class Deflater extends ZStream {
...
}

My sources:
module com.jcraft.jsch {
}
...
package com.jcraft.jsch.jzlib;
public class JUZJZLIBDeflater extends java.util.zip.Deflater {
    com.jcraft.jsch.jzlib.Deflater delegate;
}

As long as I try to compile a named module compilation fails. I see that --add-exports is useless in case of package-private elements, but I hoped that --patch-module would help. It also fails and I don't understand why.
>javac  --class-path C:\Users\basin\.m2\repository\com\github\mwiede\jsch\0.2.21\jsch-0.2.21.jar -d target/classes src/main/java/com/jcraft/jsch/jzlib/*.java
(ok)

>javac --module-path C:\Users\basin\.m2\repository\com\github\mwiede\jsch\0.2.21\jsch-0.2.21.jar -d target/classes src/main/java/com/jcraft/jsch/jzlib/*.java
src\main\java\com\jcraft\jsch\jzlib\JUZJZLIBDeflater.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
    com.jcraft.jsch.jzlib.Deflater delegate;
                         ^
  symbol:   class Deflater
  location: package com.jcraft.jsch.jzlib
1 error

>javac --module-path C:\Users\basin\.m2\repository\com\github\mwiede\jsch\0.2.21\jsch-0.2.21.jar -d target/classes --patch-module com.jcraft.jsch=src/main/java src/main/java/module-info.java src/main/java/com/jcraft/jsch/jzlib/*.java
src\main\java\com\jcraft\jsch\jzlib\JUZJZLIBDeflater.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
    com.jcraft.jsch.jzlib.Deflater delegate;
                         ^
  symbol:   class Deflater
  location: package com.jcraft.jsch.jzlib
1 error


I suspect that the fact that both of your modules have same name may be involved in this situation.

Also you exports com.jcraft.jsch, but package com.jcraft.jsch.jzlib.
